# combining variables to equal an existing variable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fill a table with appropriate dates in Javascript, and was wondering if this would work. I don't want a link to a jQuery plugin since I have my table made to my liking and want to keep using it as such. I just want to know if my logic is accurate. This is just an example not actual code snippet.

Javascript:

```
var d1 = day1;
// .
// .
// .
var d42 = lastDay;
var i = 1;

//The question then is: Does 
// d.i = d1 ? and can I use a for loop like this d.i++ to populate up to 42?
```

Remember that I don't want a jQuery plug in, it took me forever to create the calendar to my liking and don't want to have to start over and try to fit a plug in to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer: No.**

**Long answer:** You're confusing object notation with variable names. `d1` is not the same as `d[1]` or `d.i`. And `d.i` means the property `i` of `d`; not the property of `d` that matches the value of `i`. For example:

```
var i = 1,
    d = {
            1 : "foo",
            i : 42
        };
alert(d.i); // 42
```

So, the answer to your question is no, they're not the same.

You *could* use `eval` here, as in `eval('d' + i)`, but you ***must*** sanitize and validate the data before you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead if you can have

```
var days = {
   d1: day1,
   d2: day2,
   .
   .
   d42: lasDay
};
```

then you can definitely do

```
var i;
for (i = 1; i <= 42; i++) {
    console.log(days["d" + i]);
}
```

and loop.

Comment: I like this a lot, and seems to be the closest to what I want. Can I do away with "console.log" and replace it with whatever else? Since d(i) will be replaced with a month's numerical value.

Comment: Yes, you can access `days["d"+i]` and do whatever you want with it.